# Error message: main method not found even though I have one?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I get this error message:

```
Main method not found in class User, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

My file has main though...
The following is my code.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;


public class User {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("users.json"));
            System.out.println("file exists.");
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                //System.out.println(jsonObject);

                int id = i;

                String first_name = (String) jsonObject.get("first_name");
                System.out.println(first_name);

                String last_name = (String) jsonObject.get("last_name");
                System.out.println(last_name);

                String email = (String) jsonObject.get("email");
                System.out.println(email);

                String gender = (String) jsonObject.get("gender");
                System.out.println(gender);

                String interested = (String) jsonObject.get("interested");
                System.out.println(interested);

                double longitude = (double) jsonObject.get("longitude");
                System.out.println(longitude);

                double latitude = (double) jsonObject.get("latitude");
                System.out.println(latitude);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a basic code to parse all the json file to java, so that I can build a graph based on that. But I get this error message (and I googled already and found a similar error message) even though I have main method.
What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: Can you verify the String class is not defined in the same package? OR
Try changing your method signature to public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)

Comment: Do you have a custom `String` class in your project?

Comment: I am just clicking "run"

Comment: and no, I don't have a custom String class in my project.

Comment: There is no String class in my package.... and it still gives me the same error message when I try public static void main(java.lang.String[] args)

Comment: Which IDE you are using??

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil I am using Eclipse 4.7.1.

Comment: you must not be running the class file you think you are. Check your classpath, i bet somehow it's find some version of User class that is not the one you think you are compiling.

Comment: I'd suggest abandoning the IDE for a moment and try compiling it from the command line with `javac` and see if it compiles. If it does, then there is something wrong with your IDE setup. Alternatively, try reducing your code to empty `main` without any imports and see if there are any changes.